# Eclipse 4.4 Luna spellcheck preference settings are not taking effect

Tags: eclipse-luna

I have followed the steps suggested to disable spellcheck but its not taking effect is there any work around other than taking preference from old projects? and if i do so from eclipse platform like 3.3 will it making things worst?

thanks,
Rags